# Why is my margins auto adjusting so that widths are equal?

Tags: css

I have 4 columns, each 25% width and a margin 25px to the left, with the last child having a 25px margin to the right. 
Now, the result is actually what i want, each being the same width, with equal amount of margins, but I'm confused as to how it is working.
Intuitively, shouldn't the width on the last child be smaller than the previous three since not only it has a margin to the left, but also a margin to the right?

```
const Column = styled.div`
    margin-left: 25px;
    width: 25%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    &:last-child {
        margin-right: 25px;
    }
`;
```

Comment: That's not plain CSS

Comment: the width is defined by *width* so even if it has more margin, the width remain the same = 25%

Comment: "width" property applies to the content (or content+padding+border if `box-sizing: border-box`), margin does not affect the width value. Also, you are using a flex container, children are also modified by the flex-basis, flex-grow and flex-shink properties, width doesn't behave the same for children of a flex box.

Answer (score 0):

You may use margin:auto to get the same width and same margin.